# Detail about the function of such operators: +=,*=, -=, /=

Tags: java

I was studying Java and I saw this example in a book:

```
int x=2, n=3;
    int result=1;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        result*=x;
    System.out.println(result);
```

This calculates 2 to the power of 3. What I do not understand is how it does it in detail. I guess that `for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)` decides how many times `int x=2` is going to be repeated, in this case, "3", then it gets `int result=1` and multiply it by `int x=2`, and multiply `int x=2` by itself three times. Maybe I am correct, but I do not understand how it happens, and why, as it is not possible to see the process step by step in the program (is it?). Could any one help me and tell what makes `int x=2` repeat three times here, and how? And what exactly these expressions `*=` and `result*=x;` do? I saw everywhere that `a*=b` is the same as `a=a*b`, but it does not explain much how it works and in which cases I should use it, and I would really like to understand it, to know how to use it in future, in the case of I need to create a program and it may help me.

Comment: It's simply a short form for `result = result * x;` (or + x, - x, or / x).

Comment: *I saw everywhere that `a*=b` is the same as `a=a*b`, but it does not explain much how it works...* what more do you want to know? *and in which cases I should use it...* use it wherever you can; it's cleaner.

Comment: Here's a case where you can't use `*=`: `int result; result*=2;` because result needs to have a value in order to be able to do `*=`. In my opinion `a = a * 2` is just as fine as `a *= 2`. In fact, the second version takes more "brain gymnastics". And programming, like any text, is communication, as much with the computer as yourself and your colleagues. So clarity is always good.

Comment: @Erk Both versions are equally invalid if it's not initialized. As for which version is more readable, that's highly subjective and ultimately depends on convention. IMO, the shorter way is more expressive and more conventional among experienced developers.

Comment: @shmosel: I'm answering two different questions. And now I'm answering another question... ;o) And in my experience, most of the very experienced programmers tend to "move elsewhere" so you're going to work at best with intermediate programmers... but then, IRL you'll have to deal with both forms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    result*=x;
```

`i` is not used, and we know that `n=3`, so we could rewrite the code as:

```
int x = 2
int result = 1;
result *= x; // result is 2
result *= x; // result is 4
result *= x; // result is 8
System.out.println(result);
```

Regarding `a*=b` being the same as `a=a*b`, it's not *exactly* the same, but close enough. `a*=b` is the same as `a=a*(typeOfA)b` where `(typeOfA)` is a cast to the type of `a`, eg `a=a*(int)b`. This rarely causes a different result because usually the types of `a` and `b` are the same, but may have an effect due to the java's automatic widening/casting when types of `a` and `b` differ.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take it step by step:

```
int x=2, n=3;
int result=1;
```

These two lines could be simplified at most into:

```
int x;
int n;
int result;
x = 2;
n = 3;
result = 1;
```

The `int` constructs (e.g. `int x`) define a variable of type int (e.g. `x`). This means `x` can hold an integer number.

Then the `x = 2` construct sets the value of `x` to `2`.

Doing `int x=2` is a short form for that.

You're able to define and set more than one variable using the `int x=2, n=3` construct as a shorthand.

The for-loop, here with curly braces to mark the beginning and end of the block (the part of code repeating in the for-loop):

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    result*=x;
}
```

Using no curly braces means repeat the next ONE instruction.

As you pointed out yourself, the for clause loops three times.

The loop consists of the following segments:

```
for ([variable instantiations]; [condition]; [loop instruction])
```

The `variable instantiations` can (but does not have to) be used for setting up variables, usually a single variable to use as the index of the loop. In your case a new instantiation of a variable `i` with the value `1`.

The `loop condition` is used to test if the loop should continue. As long as this statement is true, the loop will. In your case a test is made of `i` against `n`. As long as `i` is less than or equal to (`<=`) `n` the loop continues.

The final `loop instruction` is a bit of code that will be performed once for each loop. In your case it will increment (`++`) `i` with one. (`i++` is equivalent to `i = i + 1`).

The instruction in the for-loop, `result *= x` means that `result` will be multiplied by `x` (2) and the result will be stored back in `result` (i.e. `result = result * 2`)

Finally, the result will be printed to the console:

```
System.out.println(result);
```

If I'm not completely mistaken you should get: `8`.